# Unable to get PHPMyAdmin to connect to Amazon RDS instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-rds

I'm unable to get PHPMyAdmin to connect to my Amazon RDS instance. I've granted permissions for my IP address to the DB Security Group which has access to this database I'm trying to access.

All I am seeing on the browser is this:

[image]

I have also added the below config in my **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'my hostname for rds';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 'my port number';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'my hostname for rds';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = FALSE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'my user';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'my pswd';
```

I have also linked this:

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/html/
```

Please guide me If I am missing something.

Comment: Can you login to instance and connect to mysql properly from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly this failure mode. Started with a working phpmyadmin for localhost; followed the guidance all over the internet for adding an RDS instance, but saw the same response page as the questioner.

Solution was to add an explicit entry for localhost, also. My config file looks like this (for interactive login - I don't include the password):

```
// Localhost
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

$i++;
// RDS
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'my RDS db DNS name';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Short name for my DB';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Now it works.